# Name 'xxx' is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt4

Why these two function want not work ?

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

 def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()
    self.setGeometry(500, 150, 500, 600)
    self.home()

 def home(self):

    btn_run = QtGui.QPushButton("Run", self)
    btn_run.clicked.connect(self.run)
    btn_run.resize(120, 40)
    btn_run.move(220, 540)

    self.show()

 def view_splash(arg1):
    label = QLabel("<font color=red size=10<b>" + n[arg1] + "</b></font>")
    label.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    label.show()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000, label.hide)

 def run(self):
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        n = random.choice(words)
        view_splash(0)
        view_splash(1)
        time.sleep(600)
```

I have that error:

```
  view_splash(0)
NameError: name 'view_splash' is not defined
```

What I'm doing wrong ?
How this should look like ?

Comment: Well `lines` isn't defined either... or `words`... :/

Comment: I haven't tried this but maybe `this.view_splash(0)` would work.

Comment: You should revise how to handle Classes in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: @Someone In Python, one would typically use `self` and not `this`.

Answer (score 1):

In python, it is necessary to use `self` to access other methods and attributes of the same object. When you simply call `view_splash`, python looks for the function definition but *will not* look at the methods of `Window`. By explicitly prefixing `view_splash` with `self.`, python then knows that you want the method `Window.view_splash` and it should work as you expect.

So for your specific code, this would require you to update your `run` method to be the following:

```
def run(self):
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        n = random.choice(words)
        self.view_splash(0)
        self.view_splash(1)
        time.sleep(600)
```

I'm assuming that there is additional code *outside* of the class which defines `lines` and `words` as global variables which `Window.run` can then access.