# TypeError: 'xxx' takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

Hier was my first question: [Name 'xxx' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114903/name-xxx-is-not-defined/36119078#36119078)

And after edit I have this error:

```
self.view_splash(0)
TypeError: view_splash() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

What do I need to do, to fix it ?

Comment: I guess you should not pass a value at all

Comment: Either don't pass an argument, or define another one on the method, depending on your needs and whether you own what you're calling. Please put a [mcve] **in this question**.

Answer (score 1):

`def view_splash(arg1):` is inside a class so you should use the staticmethod decorator

```
@staticmethod
def view_splash(arg1):
```

Comment: `@staticmethod` is unlikely to be the correct solution here.